# LastPass - maintaining security on foreign devices

Tags: password-management, lastpass

So I've recently started using LastPass to generate and store secure passwords for me (previously, I was using the same password for every service). I am in the process of changing all my passwords to randomly generated ones, which are then stored by LastPass. However, I have thought of two problems that I might have from this approach:

- The computers at my university require a login at the very start to allow access to programs, the web, etc. Currently, my university account is set up with a (long) randomly-generated password, which I can't remember. However, I cannot use LastPass to fill the password for me, as that would require me to be logged in first. Is there any way to get around this? Or would I just have to keep this password as a shorter, more memorable and less secure one?
- On occasion, I would want to be able to log in to my Google Drive, to be able to share files between computers. Similarly, this is set up with a randomly generated password stored by LastPass. Is there a way that I could safely get LastPass to fill in the password (or otherwise get into my account), without having to compromise password security? If not, is there a more secure way to share files between computers?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

There's a second option also. LastPass have their app for mobile devices.

You can access your password vault by logging into your account on your mobile device, search for your password and type it manually. Some devices also allow to use fingerprint scanner to speed up this process. It is a better option in my opinion than accessing a website on a foreign computer that may be compromised.

Comment: Yep! Never ever use Lastpass (or any password manager for that matter) on a foreign computer. You are to give away your master password.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your university password, you won't be able to use LastPass for that.  Same thing for me at work.  A long memorable password is a go.  I use 4 dictionary words separated by special characters, with preceding special or numerical characters and ending in special or numerical characters.  I find I can easily get passwords 25+ characters in length that are memorable that way.

As for getting into Google Drive, you can access LastPass database via their website on any computer.  https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=1036

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you can access Last Pass either via their website, or on your mobile phone using their app.

If you'd like to simplify the process on a PC, you can install the [LastPass extention for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lastpass-free-password-ma/hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd), which will let you search for and copy a username and password from your vault more easily (i.e. without having to open up the website).

Example: 
[image]

**A couple of recommendations if you choose to do this though:** Always remember to log out from LastPass when you're done, and be sure to require some form of two factor authentication when logging in. Personally, I'm fairly happy with [LastPass's own authenticator](https://lastpass.com/auth/) for this purpose, but there are other options too. You can find them under your settings or preferences in LastPass.